# C++ Unique Objects

Tags: c++, constructor, unique, instance, private

I would like to create a class where the possible universe of instances is limited, and of which users cannot create new instances. For example, currencies are unique, and users of the library I am working should not be able to create new currencies, or copy existing ones. It is kind of like a multiple-ton pattern, I guess. What I have so far is:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct Currency {
public:
    typedef const Currency * Pointer;

    std::string code;

    static const Currency & Get(const std::string & Code);
private:
    Currency();
    Currency(const std::string & c);
};

Currency::Currency(const std::string & c)
:code(c) {}

const Currency & Currency::Get(const std::string & Code) {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Currency> Value;
    typedef std::map<std::string, Value> MapType;
    static std::map<std::string, Value> map_;

    if (map_.empty()) {
        // Initialize your map here, from a database query or what have you...
    }
    MapType::const_iterator it = map_.find(Code);
    if (it == map_.end()) {
        throw std::exception(("[Currency::Get] Currency '" + Code + "' not found").c_str());
    }
    return *it->second;
}
```

Are there any obvious problems with this design? (I know that this isn't thread-safe)
Is there a generally accepted technique/pattern that I am not aware of that is traditionally used to achieve this?

Thanks,
Marc.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for Factory pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern.  Your `Get()` function is what would usually be called the `CreateInstance()` function, but your idea is sound.

Comment: The map will store a copy of string of its own, so public: std::string code; should be replace with a getter.  Also a Factory does not inherently limit the number of available objects.  Why do you want to limit the instances?

Comment: It's not exactly a factory pattern. I want to be able to compare objects cheaply by just comparing their address in memory. I.e., I have two cash flows, are they in the same currency? operator==(const Currnecy & rhs) just becomes {this == &rhs);}. In this case, it's important to be able to make sure that no new instances of the US dollar are inadvertently created.

Comment: @Hazerider: You already have 90% of a factory pattern. You just need to tweak it!

Comment: I guess it's really a cross between a factory and a singleton :-)

Comment: @Hazerider: See my response below for a suggestion on how to make that tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [`boost:noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) to prevent copying; that's a good reference solution that you can both trust and learn from. Preventing instantiation is easy: a `private` constructor.

Comment: Could I still put boost::noncopyable objects into a map?

Comment: @Hazerider: You could store pointers to them into the map. By making the destructor private you can make sure that noone can `delete` those pointers, too.

Comment: Constructor appears like it is already private. Also, you could prevent copying cheaply by just making the copy constructor private as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure, what you want to do, but of course there is the singleton pattern, if you want to limit the number of instances to 1 or if you want to control how the instances are created you could use the factory pattern.

Comment: The whole point is that I want to be able to limit the number of instances to X, so I can't use a straight Singleton pattern. That's why I referred to it as a multiple-ton pattern :-)

Answer (score 1):

Declare a private copy constructor `Currency::Currency(const Currency&)`, but don't define it. This prevents initialising a `Currency` object with another `Currency` object. Similarly, declare a private assignement operator `Currency& Currency::operator=(const Currency&)`. That way you prevent assigning one currency to another currency.

Comment: Making these private is enough to prevent assignment and copying. I believe I need to implement one of the two, otherwise I can't use a std::map to store the instances.

Comment: The above comment is silly. I obviously won't be able to store the instances in a map. To use these in any kind of container you have to store pointers to them (as mentioned above by Jon). Someone clever enough could probably create code that abuses that, but I am pretty sure it's difficult to do inadvertently.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about, I believe, is the Singleton pattern.  So you can read up on that.

The way in most languages to get a singleton is to

1) make your constructors private

2) instantiate a single instance (the singleton) of your class internal to the class (private static)

3) create a static (class) method that returns a pointer to the static private instance created in step #2 (typically called getInstance() or instance() or something like that.)

Anyone needing to use this singleton then calls

```
MyClass foo = MyClass::getInstance();
foo.doWork( blah blah );
```

and uses the singleton for their work.

Singletons aren't by definition (I think) thread safe, and you're right to notice that.  Adding thread safety is a separate issue.

Looks like you were most of the way there with your solution.

Comment: The problem with singleton is that I can only have one currency.

Comment: I knew I had to be missing SOMEthing.  =)

Answer (score 0):

You already have everything you need!

**EDIT:**

Just modify the part where you throw your exception:

```
if (it == map_.end()) {

    if ( -- part of allowed set -- ){
       -- create a new currency --
    }
    else {
       throw std::exception(("[Currency::Get] Currency '" + Code + "' not found").c_str());
    }
}
```

You can do your comparison to see if the currency is allowed in a variety of ways:

1. Another map, listing allowed String codes
2. A regular expression comparison on the code
3. Manually checking the code against a static array of allowed values

**EDIT2:**
Below is a completely separate answer from the one above:

From the description of your problem, you might actually want to consider using enums rather than classes to differentiate between the possible currency types.

```
enum Currency { US, CAN, JPY, CHF, EURO };

std::map<Currency curreny, std:string code>;
```

**EDIT 3:**

Add something like:

```
private:
    std::vector<Currency> initializedList;
```

And in your Get method, rather than return "it->second", return a reference to an object in the vector. If it doesn't yet exist, first populate the object into the vector.

Comment: I want the possible different currencies to be restricted to a certain set, known in advance.

Comment: @Hazerider: then add a conditional inside this conditional. if the currency is not part of your restricted set, throw an exception. otherwise, instantiate the new one!

Comment: The allowed set of currencies is initialized in the "if (map_.empty()) {...}" block. In the implementation, it goes to a database and loads all the active currencies. I don't want to have to recompile the code when a new currency becomes active. I guess you could call this lazy initialization.

Comment: Ok, then add a Vector holding all the initialized Currencies. See my edit.